# MonoTouch application crashing on device on startup in debug mode (not in release)

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a problem which is making debugging my MonoTouch application very difficult. If I do a *release* compile then the application runs correctly, but if I do a *debug* compile then the application crashes at startup and the exception does not get even get captured by MonoTouch.

I have no idea how to go about determining what is going wrong here. In Xcode organizer I see a crash log entry, but I can't make any sense of it at all. I will copy the crash log here (truncated, because it is VERY long!); hopefully someone here can shed some light on it or can give me some other way to capture the exception in MonoTouch so I can see what is going wrong.

Here is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 0E0CFEF7-A2ED-4BD5-B2C0-B5E562FB063B
CrashReporter Key:   f74aea3dbbd0dccb4bd9f7b7badfcdabe33c0ed5
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         Mobileforms [3728]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/40A88352-7F78-4085-856B-9621541774ED/Mobileforms.app/Mobileforms
Identifier:      Mobileforms
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-08-19 16:11:51.973 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x2fd00ff4
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Mobileforms 0x004c7e04 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:695)
1   Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
2   Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
3   Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
4   Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
5   Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
6   Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
7   Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
8   Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
9   Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
10  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
11  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
12  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
13  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
14  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
15  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
16  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
17  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
18  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
19  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
20  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
21  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
22  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
23  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
24  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
25  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
26  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
27  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
28  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
29  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
30  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
31  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
32  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
33  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
34  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
35  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
36  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
37  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
38  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
39  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
40  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
41  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
42  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
43  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
44  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
45  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
46  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
47  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
48  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
49  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
50  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
51  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
52  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
53  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
54  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
55  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
56  Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
57  Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
58  Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
59  Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
60  Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
501 Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
502 Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
503 Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
504 Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
505 Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
506 Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
507 Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
508 Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
509 Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
510 Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a83ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c966d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c96bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a8fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x30205032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3020603a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib                 0x302055ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c9658a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c96bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a83ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c966d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c96bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a7b60 __recvfrom + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c6428c recv + 16
2   Mobileforms 0x0034adb0 recv_length (debugger-agent.c:975)
3   Mobileforms 0x0035d170 debugger_thread (debugger-agent.c:7045)
4   Mobileforms 0x00481c70 thread_start_routine (wthreads.c:285)
5   Mobileforms 0x004bfae4 GC_start_routine (pthread_support.c:1468)
6   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
7   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a5c50 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a5f6e semaphore_wait + 2
2   Mobileforms 0x004930a8 mono_sem_wait (mono-semaphore.c:115)
3   Mobileforms 0x003ad460 finalizer_thread (gc.c:1070)
4   Mobileforms 0x004561d4 start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:774)
5   Mobileforms 0x004562c8 start_wrapper (threads.c:822)
6   Mobileforms 0x00481c70 thread_start_routine (wthreads.c:285)
7   Mobileforms 0x004bfae4 GC_start_routine (pthread_support.c:1468)
8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
9   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a5c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a5758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                    0x329382b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                    0x3293a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                    0x328caebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                    0x328cadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore     0x3114b27e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a5c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a5758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                    0x329382b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                    0x3293a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                    0x328caebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                    0x328cadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation  0x338467f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation  0x33839382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation  0x338ab5c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a5c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x332a5758 mach_msg + 44
2   SpringBoardServices               0x300f5442 SBAcquireApplicationAssertion + 134
3   SpringBoardServices               0x300f404c SBSProcessAssertionCreateForPID + 268
4   AddressBook 0x30656a74 ABCDBContextCreateWithPathAndAddressBook + 40
5   AddressBook 0x3064ca86 ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigrationInProcessLinkingAndResetSortKeys + 182
6   AddressBook 0x3064cd94 ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigration + 8
7   AddressBook 0x3064cda0 ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectory + 4
8   AddressBook 0x30659248 ABAddressBookCreate + 8
9   TextInput   0x3397a4ec KB::matchable_strings_from_address_book() + 16
10  TextInput   0x3397ea0e KB::DynamicDictionaryImpl::background_load_address_book(KB::StaticDictionary const&) + 86
11  TextInput   0x33980240 KB::BackgroundLoad(void*) + 224
12  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c9530a _pthread_start + 242
13  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x32c96bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x0095c2c0    r1: 0x0095c460      r2: 0x00130c48      r3: 0x013af408
    r4: 0x00136640    r5: 0x3f5b19dc      r6: 0x03f2e6a0      r7: 0x2fd01094
    r8: 0x00966350    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x0095c460     r11: 0x2fd01100
    ip: 0x004c7df4    sp: 0x2fd00fe4      lr: 0x00130c54      pc: 0x004c7e04
  cpsr: 0x600f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x57cfff +Mobileforms armv6  <0b0a5ab5e99f3350abdba8ddb4864453> /var/mobile/Applications/40A88352-7F78-4085-856B-9621541774ED/Mobileforms.app/Mobileforms
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30df4000 - 0x30e03fff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x30e0c000 - 0x30e43fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30e72000 - 0x30e92fff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x30e93000 - 0x30e9cfff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30e9d000 - 0x30ea3fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x30ecd000 - 0x30ed6fff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30ed7000 - 0x30ee3fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30ee4000 - 0x30ee9fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x30f30000 - 0x30f31fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x30fec000 - 0x30ff9fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x310c0000 - 0x310d9fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x31130000 - 0x3113bfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31247000 - 0x31295fff  CoreMotion armv7  <58c353bb7e33361f881da07c72f4cdfb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x31296000 - 0x3129cfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x312c5000 - 0x312c5fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x312c6000 - 0x31325fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31326000 - 0x31326fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31434000 - 0x31435fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x31436000 - 0x3146bfff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x314be000 - 0x314f6fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x314fa000 - 0x314fcfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x31508000 - 0x3150bfff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x3151d000 - 0x3151ffff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x31664000 - 0x31768fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31769000 - 0x3178dfff  MediaControl armv7  <1cfc7d79f554357ab59eb69f9efebf07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x3178e000 - 0x31794fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31795000 - 0x3179afff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3179b000 - 0x3179bfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x317e9000 - 0x31892fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31baf000 - 0x31bc5fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x31bd2000 - 0x31bd5fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31bd6000 - 0x31c5afff  AVFoundation armv7  <eeaf5f4f822436a5bd1655f536e69879> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31c6b000 - 0x31c6ffff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x31c70000 - 0x31c77fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x31ca6000 - 0x31ca9fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <4863e321afee3ac5a3749e50cd926597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x31cde000 - 0x31d25fff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x31d26000 - 0x31d4ffff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31d53000 - 0x31d82fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x31d83000 - 0x31db6fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31f32000 - 0x3253dfff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32595000 - 0x326e9fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x326ec000 - 0x3280dfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3280e000 - 0x32810fff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x32811000 - 0x32811fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x32812000 - 0x3289cfff  Message armv7  <2cce1aa95a493906bb0227197f9e4b96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x328f1000 - 0x328fdfff  HomeSharing armv7  <2df6957cdfea31aea12eebf27ca1691c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x328fe000 - 0x32905fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x329a0000 - 0x32aecfff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32b03000 - 0x32b05fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32b06000 - 0x32b10fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x32b19000 - 0x32b26fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <d454cde062983860a41694922eb5c042> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x32cd9000 - 0x32de1fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x33123000 - 0x33125fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33126000 - 0x331c3fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x331c4000 - 0x331c8fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x331d6000 - 0x33563fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33566000 - 0x335acfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x335ad000 - 0x335e0fff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x335fd000 - 0x33604fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x33650000 - 0x33684fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33685000 - 0x336aefff  ContentIndex armv7  <ecd71782cd833360872b943ecc65d203> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x336af000 - 0x33794fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x33795000 - 0x337dffff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x337e0000 - 0x3390cfff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x3393d000 - 0x3397cfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x339f0000 - 0x33a32fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33a4f000 - 0x33ad0fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33ad1000 - 0x33af1fff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x33af2000 - 0x33af7fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x33b32000 - 0x33b42fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x33b8c000 - 0x33c50fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33c61000 - 0x33cd0fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33cd1000 - 0x33ce4fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33ced000 - 0x33cf0fff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x33d34000 - 0x33e21fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x37321000 - 0x3743bfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3743c000 - 0x3743cfff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x37472000 - 0x37507fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x37536000 - 0x37584fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x37585000 - 0x375a4fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like recursion is occurring.

> 4   Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)
>
> 5   Mobileforms 0x004c8924 monotouch_static_trampoline (monotouch-glue.m:704)
>
> 6   Mobileforms 0x00130c4c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 60
>
> 7   Mobileforms 0x00288c34 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
>
> 8   Mobileforms 0x00315cfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5754)
>
> 9   Mobileforms 0x0041d6ec mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2756)

and this comes from a background thread using the addressbook.

My advice is to:

- Check if this also happens on the simulator. Are both the Debug and Release builds behaving identically ?
- Then check if all your options for your Release and Debug builds are identical. Something different could cause the code to behave differently;
- If you have any #if DEBUG inside your code (and comment them if any);
- At last resort create a small, self-contained, test case and fill a bug report to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Hi poupou. Yes, it does seem like something is being called recurively, because the same log entries are repeated over and over. I don't have any #if DEBUG inside my code... but, hmmm, I am making use of several objective c static libraries... maybe one of them could have #if DEBUG lines??? I will also try removing the static libraries one by one to see if one of the libraries are causing this.

Comment: External libraries should not matter unless you (a) rebuild them differently for Release | Debug or (b) link a different version based on Release | Debug. OTOH your strategy to remove, one by one, the external libraries is a good one! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I was running into the same issue where the app would hard crash and the stack trace appeared to be recursively calling the same functions (same error as OP).

The issue with our app was that we didn't include the proper gcc_flags for one of the frameworks that was referenced by a static library. In our case, we had to add the following argument into mtouch since one of the static libraries we were using relies on the ExternalAccessory.framework:

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -framework ExternalAccessory -ObjC"
```

After I added that, our app stopped crashing and starting working as intended.

I hope this answer can prevent someone from pulling their hair out like I did!

Comment: Thanks Zach for your answer. Hopefully it will help someone else... and I can identify with the pulling of hair out! :) I found this problem to be highly annoying, especially as the crash log does not give you anything meaningful to help identify the problem. In our situation, though, this problem *eventually* went away after a particular update of Monotouch. So I have no idea what was causing this for us. But I think that you are are right that it relates to static libraries as we use static libraries extensively in our project. Thanks for sharing your solution to this problem.